# How is hot reload implemented in Meteor JS?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, reload, meteor

I'm interested in knowing what kind of strategies they use to push code to the browser when a file is changed, yet I have found nothing on the internet about it. I also searched the code at their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/meteor/meteor) to no avail.

So, how is the hot reload implemented in Meteor? 
Are there any alternatives?
Is it possible to implement code and assets reload using SocketIO in Node?

Comment: No, the impressive feature is precisely that the server is not restarted and the browser must not be refreshed to see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_deps):

> Meteor's implementation of reactivity is short and sweet, about 50
>   lines of code. You can hook into it yourself to add new reactive
>   contexts or data sources, using the Meteor.deps module.
>
> Meteor has a simple dependency tracking system, so that it it can
>   automatically rerender templates and such when Session variables are
>   modified, or database queries change.
>
> Unlike most other systems, you don't have to manually declare these
>   dependencies — it "just works". The mechanism is simple and efficient.
>   When you call a function that supports reactive updates (say, a
>   database query), it automatically saves the current "invalidation
>   context" object if any (say, the current template being rendered.)
>   Later, when the data changes, it can "invalidates" this context (tell
>   the template to rerender itself.) The whole implementation is about 50
>   lines of code.
>
> Developers, particularly package authors, can use invalidation
>   contexts to implement additional reactive data sources or to write
>   functions that automatically register dependencies on reactive data
>   sources.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the tip, now I'll investigate if this handles code push also.

Comment: The implementation is no longer that _short and sweet_ anymore. :-)

Comment: Seems like the question was about pushing new versions of the client JS code, not about reactive data